# Arch Linux: how to find package that provides requirement

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I'd like to query the pacman database for the package that satisfies a requirement: essentially the package that would get installed if I were to run `pacman -S <requirement>`.

It appears there are three cases:

- The requirement is the name of a package.
- The requirement is the name of a file or library.
- The requirement appears in the `provides` field of another package.

The first two cases are pretty straightforward, but the third one is causing me trouble.

For example, the requirement `apache-ant` is provided by package `ant`.
`pacman -S apache-ant` correctly identifies and installs ant.
`pacman -Q apache-ant` returns the information I want, *but only if the package is already installed*.

Is there a command that works similarly to `pacman -Q`, but does not fail if the package isn't locally installed?

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in method for the third case, but I've used this:

```bash
pacprovides(){
    pacman -Si | sed -n '/^Name.*: /{s///;h}; /^Provides.*'"$1"'/{g; p}'
}
```

`h`old the package name, `g`et and `p`rint it when you find a matching line.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pacman -F string1 string2 ...`

Refer to : [Querying package databases](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Querying_package_databases)

Comment: `pacman -F` works in second the case, where I'm looking for the package that provides a file, but fails in the third: `pacman -F apache-ant` returns no results, while I want a command that returns `ant`.

Answer (score 0):

`--print` shows the targets of a transaction:

> $ pacman --sync **--print** libtagparser.so
>
> file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/cpp-utilities-5.20.0-100-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
>
> file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/tagparser-11.5.0-100-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst

The package is the **last target**, trimmed:

> $ pacman --sync **--print** libtagparser.so | **tail** -n1 | rev | **cut** --delimiter='/' --fields=1 | **cut** --delimiter='-' --fields=4- | rev
>
> tagparser